# Tomar el valor de 2 input y concatenarlos en un solo campo del fromGroup antes de enviar un post Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un formulario donde el documento de identidad se compone de un select donde se elige el tipo de documento (V, E ...) y un imput en el que se agrega el numero de documento (1234567). Necesito tomar ambos valores y pasarlos en un solo campo ejemplo (V1234567) al momento de realizar el post

```
accountTo: this.fb.group({
    bankId: ['0134'],
    phoneNum: ['584166399552'],
    customerId: ['V11673945']
 })
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola Tomas, puedes hacer un tercer donde el tercer input se complete con el contenido de los otros dos?

Comment: puedes darme un ejemplo de lo que propones?